# How to get unique values from a specific key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

Give I have a list with dictionaries and I want to get all unique values from the key first_name from the dictionaries, how do I do that in python?

```
data = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "John"
},
{   "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Mary"
},
{   "id": 3,
    "first_name": "John"
}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [**set comprehension**](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/set_comprehension.html) :

```
first_names = {d["first_name"] for d in data}
```

Comment: This is going to yield duplicates. Even in OPs example.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> set(i["first_name"] for i in data)
{'John', 'Mary'}
```

if you want a `list` instead of `set` you can convert it to list:

```
>>> list(set(i["first_name"] for i in data))
['John', 'Mary']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the operator `itemgetter()` to dictionaries in the list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

iget = itemgetter('first_name')

set(map(iget, data))
# {'Mary', 'John'}
```